# How to get usage based optimization working on SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas

I have set up the configuration for SSAS to log the usage into the database, since the table did not exist I let it do that. However SSAS created the table OlapQueryLog under the schema of the SSAS service account. The logging of the queries against SSAS works fine, however when using the usage based optimization wizard it fails, because it expects the table OlapQueryLog to be under the [dbo] schema. I'm puzzled that one part of SSAS is able to write to the table and another part can't find the table, one would assume they both use the same meta information to figure out where to look for their required table.

Where and how can I tell the wizard to use the table that SSAS created ?

Comment: Can you move them to `dbo` and see if it "just works"? Almost every tool I've seen either creates these objects in `dbo` or forces that upon you because it doesn't handle schemas correctly...

Comment: I created the table under dbo, however the SSAS is still logging to the table under service account schema, and the wizard is telling me the table in the dbo schema is obviously empty.

Comment: Okay. Check the default schema of the database user being used to write/read to these tables. It probably needs to be set to `dbo`.